# enhancing java code to be more efficient

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to expand a GWT tree using selenium and i did successfully with that code

```
for (int i = 0; i < elem.size(); i++) {
 if (!elem.get(i).isExpanded() || !elem.get(i).isLeaf()) {
  elem.get(i).toggleExpand();
 }
 for (int j = 0; j < elem.get(i).getChildren().size(); j++) {
  if (!elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).isExpanded() || 
                        !elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).isLeaf()) {
   elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).toggleExpand();
  }
  for (int k = 0; k < elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).getChildren().size(); k++) {
   if (!elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).getChildren().get(k).isExpanded() ||
              !elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).getChildren().get(k).isLeaf()) {
    elem.get(i).getChildren().get(j).getChildren().get(k).toggleExpand();
   }.....
  }
 }
}
```

My question is how to enhance that code or how to put in recursive method ?

Comment: This should probably go on [codereview.se].

Comment: You just need to google `how to use recursion in java`.and when you learn how to use it ,apply it to your code and if you failed then you can post a question and we can help you

Comment: Efficient in what way: Resource (i.e. CPU, memory etc.) utilization? Development efficiency? Maintainance? ...

Comment: @Thomas .. development efficency

Comment: One thing you could do is replace those calls to `elem.get(i)` etc. with one that assigns the result to a local variable and reuse that.

Comment: @Thomas .. can you write a sample ?

Comment: Add an inner loop inside the first one that iterates over all the children in the node being processed and pass that child node to this method.

Comment: Instead of directly solving your problem using recursion, I suggest try printing the folder and file names in you directory recursively.

Comment: @duffymo .. i am beginner :) .. can you write a sample for code of what do you mean ?

Comment: @Azodious ..  .. i am beginner :) .. can you write a sample for code of what do you mean ?

Comment: @meromero then you should not be afraid of writing code yourself. search on Google, SO ... come out with code snippet and in case of issues, you know where to find us.

Answer (score 1):

To make that code more readable there are a few things you could do (:

Reuse method results, e.g. that of `elem.get(i)` or use an extended for-loop (if `elem` etc. support that):

```
for (int i = 0; i < elem.size(); i++) {
  ElementClass element = elem.get(i);
  if (!element.isExpanded() || !element.isLeaf()) {
    element.toggleExpand();
  }

  ...
}
```

Additionally since you seem to do the same for the element and it's children you could provide a method e.g.:

```
public void expandIfNeeded(ElementClass element) {
  if (!element.isExpanded() || !element.isLeaf()) {
    element.toggleExpand();
  }
}
```

Then you loop could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elem.size(); i++) {
  ElementClass element = elem.get(i);
  expandIfNeeded( element );

  ... //handle children here and call the same method for those (could also be using recursion)
}
```

Additionally, if you don't need the index `i` and `elem` is iterable you could use the extended for:

```
for ( ElementClass element : elem ) {
  expandIfNeeded( element );

  ... //handle children here and call the same method for those (could also be using recursion)
}
```

And of course recursion would make it more readable, especially if you don't know the depth of the tree:

```
//I'm assuming "elem" is a List<ElementClass> here
public void expandElements( List<ElementClass> elem ) {
  for ( ElementClass element : elem ) {
    expandIfNeeded( element );
    expandElements( element.getChildren() );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unreadable code.

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elem.size(); i++) {
  if (!elem.get(i).isExpanded()) {
    elem.get(i).toggleExpand();
  }
  // I don't know what this method returns; no time to research for you
  List<Element> children = elem.get(i).getChildren();
  for (int j = 0; j < children.size(); j++) {
      // don't know what you call it; must be a void method of some kind
      yourMethodName(children.get(i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively toggled the element by using following code.

```
public static void toggleElement(Element elem){

        if(elem.isExpand() || elem.isLeaf()){
            return;
        }else{
            elem.toggledExpand();
        }
        List<Element> children=elem.getChildren();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            toggleElement(children.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.